# DT_REG undeclared (first use in this function) and -std=c99

Tags: c

I'm writing a C program using Eclipse CDT.  I want to init my for loops like this ...

```
for( int i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
```

so I added -std=c99 to the gcc command line.  This has the side effect of throwing the error: ‘DT_REG’ undeclared (first use in this function) for the line:

```
if( dir_ent->d_type != DT_REG )
```

DT_REG is defined in dirent.h (which is included).  The code compiles fine without -std=c99 on the gcc command line.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What happens with `-std=gnu99`?  It looks like the `d_type` field is non-standard (see [the GNU libc manual page "Directory Entries"](http://www.gnu.org/s/libc/manual/html_node/Directory-Entries.html)) and so the enum that represents the directory entry types is disabled in strictly compliant mode.  It looks like you need to define `_BSD_SOURCE` (or `_GNU_SOURCE`) to get the type values.

Comment: gnu99 did the trick.  Thanks for link, it helped clarify things.